# php send post request with a case?

Tags: php, post, switch-statement

I have the following method to send a post request from my back-office php script to another php script :

```
$url = "ajax.php"; 
$res = @file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create([
    "http" => [
               "method" => "POST",
               "content" => http_build_query($params, $_REQUEST['action'] = 'save_attach_command'),
              ],
]));
```

The 'ajax.php' is a long script divised in switch case, I want to enter in 'save_attach_command' case, what am I doing wrong ?

Any help will be appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) wrong. The second parameter to it is;

> **numeric_prefix**
>   If numeric indices are used in the base array and this parameter is provided, it will be prepended to the numeric index for elements in the base array only.

Therefore the code should be :

```
$url = "ajax.php";
$params['action'] = 'save_attach_command';
$res = @file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create([
    "http" => [
        "method" => "POST",
        "content" => http_build_query($params),
    ],
]));
```